# Remove time data from string date

Tags: typescript

I have diferent dates like it:

"2021-04-25T00:00:00.000Z"

all the dates are strings

so how can I remove "T00:00:00.000Z" from de date with typescript?

Comment: try .toLocaleDateString()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method to split the date string by the "T" and get the first one.

```js
const str = "2021-04-25T00:00:00.000Z";
const output = str.split("T")[0];

console.log(output);
```